# Heap Sort giving wrong output

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

Struggled with the heap sort algorithm, figured it out eventually, but still does not work, and I cannot seem to find the problem, maybe because I have been staring at it for the past 3 hours..
The problem is that it gives wrong input. The program compiles and gives no errors. I used Visual Studio 2013.
Input: { 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 5, 4, 7, 8, 1 }
Expected Output: Array sorted.

Output: 1 2 3 5 7 1 4 4 7 8 5 8

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void change(int *a, int *b){
    int aux;
    aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}
void OrganizeHeap(int *A, int n, int i){
    int left = i * 2 + 1, right = i * 2 + 2;
    int largest = i;
    if (left < n && A[left] >= A[i])
        largest = left;

    if (right < n && A[right] >= A[i])
        largest = right;

    if (largest != i){
        change(&A[i], &A[largest]);
            OrganizeHeap(A, n, largest);
    }
}
void BuildHeap(int *A, int n){
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        OrganizeHeap(A, n, i);
}
void HeapSort(int *A, int n){
    BuildHeap(A, n);
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        change(&A[0], &A[i]);
        OrganizeHeap(A, i, 0);
    }
}
int main() {
    int max;
    int A[] = { 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8, 5, 4, 7, 8, 1 };
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);
    HeapSort(A, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to include what is the expected output and what output you received. You need to include your input as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code

```
    if (right < n && A[right] >= A[i])
          largest = right;
```

What if `A[i]` is `5`, `A[left]` is `7` then `largest` will be set to `left`.
Now what if A[right] is `6`.A[right] is greater than `A[i]` so largest will be set to `right`.`largest` should be `left` and not `right` because `A[left] > A[right]`
So you can do something like

```
  if (right < n && A[right] >= A[largest]) //see note below
```

The second problem has already been removed after the code was edited.

Note:

while checking you could just use `>` then instead of `>=`

Comment: Omg...can`t believe I didn`t saw that. Thank you! You just saved me several hours! Indeed, I posted it with a minor problem, saw it when editing. Thanks again :)